# PHP switch() clause not working as expected

Tags: php

I have this PHP switch:

```
<?php

$destination = isset($_GET['act']);
switch ($destination) {


    default:
        echo "test";
        break;

    case "manage":
        echo "manage things";
        break;

    case "create":
        echo "create things";

        break;


}

?>
```

However, when I go to `test.php?act=create`, the output is `manage things` not `create things`, and when I go to `test.php?act=manage` -- of course I get `manage things`.

So ... how do I fix this?

Comment: Try putting your `default:` at the end instead of at the beginnning.

Comment: @Fred-ii- That did not work.

Comment: My mistake. Well there are many good answers below that work. I tried most of them.

Comment: @Fred-ii- You tried and that is all I can ask. Thank you.

Comment: You're most welcome. Glad you found your solution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

php's [isset](https://www.php.net/isset) returns a boolean. So $destination is either true or false, not a string.

Try

```
if(isset($_GET['act']))
    $destination = $_GET['act'];
```

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is:

```
$destination = isset($_GET['act']);
```

`isset` returns either `true` or `false`, never any of the string values you are using.

You could use something like:

```
$destination = isset($_GET['act']) ? $_GET['act'] : '';
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use:

```
<?php

if(isset($_GET['act'])) $destination = $_GET['act'];

switch ($destination) {

    case "manage":
        echo "manage things";
        break;

    case "create":
        echo "create things";
        break;

    default:
        echo "test";

}
```

Or just use:

```
$destination = @$_GET['act'];
```

Comment: **Don't** use `@$_GET['act']`. Changing `$destination` will change superglobal value