# how to make redirect that includes data about the link that was clicked?

Tags: php, html

I have a page with two links (text link & banner link),
that should lead to the **same** redirect page
 (on my domain).

The redirect would be to a link that shall include a variable,
that indicates which of the two link was clicked.

e.g.:

```
<?php
header("Location: http://external-domain.com/?ref=[value]");
die();
?>
```

wheareas the "value" should be "text" / "banner" or something similar.

How can I do this? 
I'm not a web programmer at all so I don't have much technical knowledge,

I guess **one possible solution (which I would rather avoid)** would be to give a separate id for the text link and for the banner, e.g.:

text link:

```
 http://mydomain.com/redirect.php?id=text
```

banner link:

```
 http://mydomain.com/redirect.php?id=banner
```

whereas redirect.php would contain:

```
<?php
$source = $_GET['id']
?>

<?php
header("Location: http://external-domain.com/?ref=<?php print $source; ?>");
die();
?>
```

But that would mean that I have to use a **different** id for these internal links;
I would rather find a way to use the **same** exact internal links (maybe for example, have each link in a "div" or a "class" and get the div/class name somehow, and have them appear as the [value].

***EDIT:**
Let me emphasize again: I'm looking for a way to do this **without having to use any "?id=[something]"** at the end of the text link or the banner link.

Thanks!

Comment: You could use a `switch/case` --- [**See this Q&A's on SO**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19697116/php-switch-not-working) --- it's a simple solution.

Comment: a simple solution for what? maybe the question isn't clear enough - I'm looking for a way to this this without using an ?id ad the end of the either the text or the image link. If I'm already using a different ID I can use my own method, can't I?

Comment: You want to pass a parameter using `GET` without an ID at the end; you're contradicting yourself. What I now think you may want to look into, is [`mod_rewrite()`](http://www.sitepoint.com/guide-url-rewriting/) Other than that, I don't know what else to suggest to you. You need to give me a real-world example; your question is confusing.

Comment: I don't want to use 'GET', that's only a possible method which I prefer to avoid...

Comment: Sorry, I'm out of options. What's the purpose of this btw, tracking?

Comment: yes, though I'm trying to use as less variables as possible to make future changes easier. If it's impossible then I'll go ahead with the first method, just wanted to be sure :)

Comment: If you're afraid of the implications that a GET could bring, you could use a button instead of an `href` link, then use POST along with conditional statements. Good luck :) cheers

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$source = $_GET['id']
?>

<?php
header("Location: http://external-domain.com/?ref=<?php print $source; ?>");
die();
?>
```

should be

```
<?php
$source = $_GET['id'];
header("Location: http://external-domain.com/?ref=".$source);
die();
?>
```

Basic concatenation.

Answer (score 0):

If you're already outputting the banner/text do this for the banner

```
<a href="http://mydomain.com/redirect.php?id=banner"><img src="imageHere.png"></a>
```

And this for the text

```
<a href="http://mydomain.com/redirect.php?id=text">text here</a>
```

Then catch the id get values with

```
<?php
$id = $_GET['id'];
if ($id == 'banner'){
    echo 'The clicked link was a banner';
}
else{
    echo 'The clicked link was text';
}
```

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear enough, I'm not looking to echo anything about the type of link that was clicked; the redirect link would eventually lead to a shopping cart page; I have a report that shows whenever an item was purchased, and there's an option to add my own data to this report. I would like to add data that would indicate what type of link the visitor had clicked. therefore I need an indicator for this already at the redirect link level. thanks.

Comment: The echo was just meant to debug.
Just catch the get variable and then put it in your database or whatever you want with it :)

Comment: `echo` is just a means of success. You can pass whatever you want in there to replace it, be it a header redirect, a DB update, an include statement, etc. @jayjay if it echoes, it's good news. ;-)

Comment: then maybe I'm missing something, but I'm not sure how does this answer contribute to my question? I've already suggested the way of using a separate ID for each link, and demonstrated how I would incorporate that ID into the second redirect link.

Comment: Your question is to check what is clicked (text or a banner), right?
If so, then I answered your question, else, could you then explain your question again?

Comment: My question is to check what was clicked, **without having to use an "?id=[something]" at the end of the link.** I want to find a way to do this while having the exact same link for both text and banner link, with no id at all.

Comment: As far as I know it's not possible to check what kind of link it was (banner or text) without using post or get variables.
What you could do, if you really wanna make it hard for yourself and don't use the id variable, use javascript to make a post call when the link is clicked, although I won't recommend that and just use example.php?link=banner or example.php?link=text.